# documentation of SetWindowsHookEx question

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I don't really understand the documentation of `SetWindowsHookEx()`. I know what to put in the first argument, but for the second, third and fourth i'm confused.
Second argument askes HOOKPROC is that just like a regular windows proc?
For third and fourth i don't get them.  So can you guys explain them for me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API documentation explains all the arguments better than anyone here can: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

The **second** argument is either NULL or a pointer to an HOOKPROC. Note that "If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL. Otherwise, lpfn can point to a hook procedure in the code associated with the current process." Here is an example HOOKPROC from MSDN:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(
  int nCode, 
  WPARAM wParam, 
  LPARAM lParam
)
{
   // process event
   ...

   return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The **third** argument must be "set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.

The **fourth** is "The identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated. If this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread."

Comment: Wait... so i set thrid argument NULL if fourth is not NULL

Comment: @Mike yes, that's correct, and unless you want to intercept all messages from all threads on the same desktop, you'll want to set the third to NULL and the fourth to `GetCurrentThreadId()`. Please click the check mark next to the top left of this answer if it is indeed the answer.

Comment: @Mike you'll need to search the internet for a way to get a process id from a process name. It's easy to find.

Comment: Obviously the Windows API documentation doesn't do such a good job of explaining the arguments, otherwise @Mike wouldn't have posted his question (and I wouldn't have found this in my search for similar info). The signature of HOOKPROC is not explained at all. A reasonable **guess** would be that it's the same as a normal WndProc - but it's equally reasonable that HOOKPROC could have an extra argument with the handle of the hook returned by SetWindowsHookEx.

Comment: Also, can the second argument really be NULL? I don't see any point in that, and the API documentation makes no mention of that possibility.